# Javascript validation form with '[]'

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, input

Hey guys i'm newbie with javascript.

I can do with input name 'nim' and function form.nim.value ==""

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function validasi_input(form){
      if (form.nim.value == ""){
        alert("NIM still empty!");
        form.nim.focus();
        return (false);
      }
    return (true);
    }
    </script>
    <form name="frm" method="post" onsubmit="return validasi_input(this)">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>NIM</td>
            <td><input class="textbox" type="text" name="nim" /></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><input class="tombol" type="submit" name="SUPDATE" value="submit"/></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

but i can't do with input name 'vn[nim]' and form.vn[nim].value ==""

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function validasi_input(form){
      if (form.vn[nim].value == ""){
        alert("NIM still empty!");
        form.vn[nim].focus();
        return (false);
      }
    return (true);
    }
    </script>
    <form name="frm" method="post" onsubmit="return validasi_input(this)">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>NIM</td>
            <td><input class="textbox" type="text" name="vn[nim]" value="<?php echo $vn['nim']; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><input class="tombol" type="submit" name="SUPDATE" value="submit"/></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

How can i do that with 'vn[nim]' ?, Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the bracket syntax instead to access the property value:

```
form['vn[nim]'].value
```

Doing this avoids the ambiguity of square brackets being used as array dereferencing.

Comment: Hi jack,
Thanks for your answer, but i can't do with your script.
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validasi_input(form){
      if (form.['vn[nim]'].value == ""){
        alert("NIM still empty!");
        form.['vn[nim]'].focus();
        return (false);
      }
    return (true);
    }
    </script>

Comment: @Gasta What do you mean by "can't do"?

Comment: with your script, No popup alert that say "NIM still empty" if i empty the input... Sorry for my bad english..

Comment: oh it's work , thanks @jack, i forget remove "dot" in form.['vn[nim]'].value .

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector("input[name='vn[nim]']").value == "";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Trm8G/

Comment: Hi Derek 朕會功夫,
Thanks for your answer, how can i do that?. 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validasi_input(form){
      if (document.querySelector("input[name='vn[nim]']").value == ""){
        alert("NIM still empty!");
        form.['vn[nim]'].focus();
        return (false);
      }
    return (true);
    }
    </script>
Should i do this. Sorry i'm newbie.